# Regex - How to split this string in two parts

Tags: regex, string, powershell, split

I would like to split this string in two parts :

```
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US
```

I would like that it splits always after `Setup.exe`, so it should be :

```
$part1 = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe"
$part2 = "/P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US"
```

What should be the function to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: You could split on the first occurrence of a space after `.exe`: `$string -split '(?<=^.*\.exe)\s'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few alternatives for you:

```
$string = 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US'
```

**Method 1:** use `-split`

```
$part1, $part2 = $string -split '^(.+\.exe)\s(.+)$'
$part1   # --> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe
$part2   # --> /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US
```

**Method 2:** use `[regex].Match()`

```
$part1, $part2 = ([regex]'(?i)^(.+\.exe)\s(.+)$').Match($string).Groups[1..2].Value
$part1   # --> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe
$part2   # --> /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US
```

**Method 3:** use `-replace` combined with method `.Split()`

```
$part1, $part2 = ($string -replace '^(.+\.exe)\s(.+)$', '$1|$2').Split('|')
$part1   # --> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe
$part2   # --> /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US
```

**Method 4:** use string methods `.IndexOf()` and `.Substring()`

```
$split = $string.IndexOf('.exe')
if ($split -ge 0) {
    $part1 = $string.Substring(0, $split + 4)
    $part2 = $string.Substring($split + 5)
}

$part1   # --> C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe
$part2   # --> /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US" 
$array = $string -Split "(Setup.exe)"
$array[0]+$array[1]
$array[2]
```

There can be other simple ways. This is One way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just splitting on whitespace and putting them back together.  You might not even have to join together the $part2 array depending on your use as an -argumentlist or with the call operator.

```
$string = 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2021 - English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe /P {28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D} /M AOEM /language en-US'
$split = -split $string

$split
C:\Program
Files\Autodesk\DWG
TrueView
2021
-
English\Setup\en-us\Setup\Setup.exe
/P
{28B89EEF-4356-0409-0100-CF3F3A09B77D}
/M
AOEM
/language
en-US

$part1 = $split[0..5] -join ' '
$part2 = $split[6..$split.length] -join ' '
# $part2 = $split[6..$split.length]
```